How to make the USB connection default to file transfer on Android 14 (and newer)?
In the past, I could choose the default USB connection function on Android using Developer Options.
Settings->Additional Settings->Developer Options->Default USB Configuration->File Transfer/Android Auto
and
Settings->Additional Settings->Developer Options->Select USB Configuration->MTP
However, this does not work with Oppo OnePlus Ace 2 Pro. Each time I connect a cable, a popup appears, and I have to tap on "File Transfer" manually. There are rumors that this (anti)"feature" is omnipresent on Android 14, but I am not sure about that.
How do I disable such a behaviour? Assume root is available, and I am not afraid of breaking CTS/SafetyNet, and rebuilding the kernel.

It's not universal, maybe a Oneplus issue. On my Pixel 6a Android 14 the selected default works. If you don't select any it falls back to File Transfer/Auto

Most likely OnePlus has modified the USB dialog and/or the logic behind it and by this modification removed the code that applies the pre-selection from developer menu. Therefore I would report this as bug to OnePlus.
